# Kentor.AuthServices.StubIdp - Discovery Service: Entity ID of Selected Idp shows up wrong when setup as an application

Tags: kentor-authservices

I have setup Kentor AuthServices SP and Idp end-points on a server.

SP: https://[domain]/SP/AuthServices/SignIn
Idp: https://[domain]/IdP/

When DiscoveryService accessed from SignIn page, 
Entity ID of Selected Idp shows up as https://[domain]/IdPMetadata, and 
SP Single Logout URL as https://[domain]/IdPLogout?SAMLRequest=[saml request]

I fixed that by modifying UrlResolver.GetCombinedUrl() so that it shows up correctly as follows...
https://[domain]/IdP/Metadata
https://[domain]/IdP/Logout?SAMLRequest=[saml request]

Is this a bug in a repository or am I missing something in configuration?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known bug "[Stubidp gives wrong entity id in virtual directory](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/issues/174)" when installing the stub idp in a virtual directory. I assume that these problems you are experiencing are related.

Comment: Hi Anders, That seems to be the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Anders, Just to get the clarity on stub idp sample; I am not understanding how the kentor samples(Id/Mvc/Owin) can call the Stub idp 52071/Metadata; when I run Id or mvc or Owin sample in all startup they are loading metadata from 52071; how ? pls explain; thnx in advance;

Comment: @Saurabh That's another question, please post it as a new one.